# Unity3D: How to programmatically test new UI features

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, automated-tests

I have an app built in Unity which uses the new canvas features including buttons and inputfields.

I'm wondering how I could implement automated testing by programmatically entering characters into the input fields and clicking buttons.
In the case of the button the UI.Button component doesnt seem to have a click method you can call.
Is there a way of registering mouse clicks at the buttons location? Or some other way of achieving this?

Comment: Is your automated testing app a separate process to your Unity app?  OS?  Windows? OSX? iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, This is how you click a button programmatically

MyButton.onClick.Invoke();

and for the inputfields you can just set their text fields like so..

MyInput.text = "flooopybloopybloo";